# Перенос кода с Jquery на нативный JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, uikit

Есть часть кода на `jQuery`, который без проблем работает:

```
<script>
var $triggerElement = $('.uk-lightbox.uk-open');
$(document).on('itemshow', $triggerElement, function() {
    alert('itemshow!');
});
</script>
```

Нужно это перенести на нативный `JS`, я сделал:

```
<script>
var el = document.querySelector('.uk-lightbox.uk-open');
el.addEventListener('itemshow',function () {
    alert('itemshow!');
});
</script>
```

Но у меня ошибка:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: А почему вы в jquery варианте обработчик на document вешаете, а в нативном - на элемент? Вешайте в нативном варианте тоже на документ и будет вам щастье

Comment: @Darth спасибо)

Comment: Если бы всё так просто было) У вас скрипт в начале html подключен? На момент его выполнения вашего элемента нет в DOM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let el = document.querySelector('.uk-lightbox.uk-open');

el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    el.style.background = 'red';
});
```

```html
<div class="uk-lightbox uk-open">Lorem ipsum</div>
```